# Setting scaling factor

Tags: gnome, scaling

I'm trying to set my scaling to 1.75 but when I type

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1.75
```

I get this error:

```
invalid character in number 1.75
                             ^
```

Is there a way I can have it take a decimal setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.75
```

This will work with decimals.

Comment: Yes, indeed it will work with decimals. Thank you.

Comment: @karel Your welcome. =)

Answer (score 2):

No, decimals aren't allowed for this setting. Use `1` or `2` (or another whole number).

Comment: So that's no way to set my scaling to 1.5 or 1.75? 1 is too small and 2 is too big

Comment: I set the scaling to 1 and upped the font scaling and that seemed to work well